# Scala Maven Build Error - scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers

Tags: scala, maven

I am getting this error while trying to build my code, but it does not provide much detail. Has anyone seen this before, the weird part is it only sometimes happens when I build:

```
[ERROR] error: java.lang.StackOverflowError
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5340)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.transformedOrTyped(Typers.scala:5605)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedValDefImpl(Typers.scala:1995)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedValDef(Typers.scala:1958)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5306)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3047)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2381)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5463)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedIf$1(Typers.scala:4255)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5319)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2382)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5463)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedLabelDef(Typers.scala:2296)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5334)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3047)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2381)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.transformedOrTyped(Typers.scala:5605)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedDefDef(Typers.scala:2208)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5308)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3047)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1921)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedClassDef(Typers.scala:1762)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5309)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3047)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3151)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2381)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedArg(Typers.scala:3164)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$class.typedArgWithFormal$1(PatternTypers.scala:112)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$$anonfun$2.apply(PatternTypers.scala:115)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$$anonfun$2.apply(PatternTypers.scala:115)
[INFO]  at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$map$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:46)
[INFO]  at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$map$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:44)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
[INFO]  at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$.map$extension(Tuple2Zipped.scala:44)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$class.typedArgsForFormals(PatternTypers.scala:115)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedArgsForFormals(Typers.scala:111)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$handleMonomorphicCall$1(Typers.scala:3470)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.doTypedApply(Typers.scala:3495)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4546)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:644)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedArg(Typers.scala:3164)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$class.typedArgWithFormal$1(PatternTypers.scala:112)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$$anonfun$2.apply(PatternTypers.scala:115)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$$anonfun$2.apply(PatternTypers.scala:115)
[INFO]  at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$map$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:46)
[INFO]  at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$map$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:44)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
[INFO]  at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$.map$extension(Tuple2Zipped.scala:44)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$class.typedArgsForFormals(PatternTypers.scala:115)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedArgsForFormals(Typers.scala:111)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$handleMonomorphicCall$1(Typers.scala:3470)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.doTypedApply(Typers.scala:3495)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4546)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2382)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2382)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5463)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedIf$1(Typers.scala:4255)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5319)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5463)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedIf$1(Typers.scala:4255)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5319)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2382)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedOutsidePatternMode$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:5318)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5317)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5463)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedIf$1(Typers.scala:4255)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5319)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:698)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2382)
...
```

Comment: Maybe try bumping stack size.

Comment: Mhh, could you please share the output of mvn dependency:tree -U
Moreover, scala and java version, what is default java version?. What version is Maven using (you can check with mvn -v).

Answer (score 2):

Found out if I change this setting in my maven pom it now works:

```
<plugin>
                   <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                   <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>${scala.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <displayCmd>true</displayCmd>
                       <jvmArgs>
                           <jvmArg>-Xss2048K</jvmArg>
                       </jvmArgs>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
```

Specifically:

```
                       <jvmArgs>
                           <jvmArg>-Xss2048K</jvmArg>
                       </jvmArgs>
```

Comment: it's been years now but do you remember if you bumped up the heap memory in the <jvmArg> section to solve this issue ?